# border of the second step inputs are red by default

Tags: angular, angular-material

input border are red before I touch the input it add invalid class by default I want to control the validation only when I click submit

[here is ts file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oGXj.png)

[here is the template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzFvz.png)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzFvz.png): [https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5Fyh.png`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5Fyh.png%60) 
Setting up your password
<form [formGroup]="PasswordFormGroup">
Password (required)

<input matInput [type]="!passwordType ? 'password' : 'text'" formControlName="password"
placeholder="Password" required>
<mat-hint class="text-danger" *ngIf="PasswordFormGroup.get('password').hasError('minlength')">
The minimum length for this field is
{{PasswordFormGroup.get('password').errors.minlength.requiredLength}}
characters.

```
        <h6 class="font-weight-bold">Repeat your password (required)</h6>
        <mat-form-field class="col-12 px-0" appearance="outline">
          <input matInput [type]="!passwordType ? 'password' : 'text'" formControlName="repeatPW"
            placeholder="repeat your Password" required>
          <mat-hint class="text-danger" *ngIf="PasswordFormGroup.get('repeatPW').hasError('minlength')">
            The minimum length for this field is
            {{PasswordFormGroup.get('repeatPW').errors.minlength.requiredLength}}
            characters.
          </mat-hint>
          <mat-hint class="text-danger"
            *ngIf="PasswordFormGroup.get('repeatPW').errors && PasswordFormGroup.get('repeatPW').errors.confirmPasswordValidator">
            password does not match</mat-hint>
        </mat-form-field>

        <div class="col-12 px-1">
          <mat-checkbox (change)="passwordType = !passwordType">Show Password</mat-checkbox>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 mt-4 d-flex justify-content-between">
            <button matStepperPrevious class="btn btn-underlined">Back</button>
            <button mat-button mat-raised-button color="primary" class="font-weight-bold"
              [disabled]="!PasswordFormGroup.valid" (click)="submitNewCompany()">
              <app-spinner *ngIf="loading" [type]="'inline'" [theme]="'text-light'"></app-spinner>
              Complete sign up
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </mat-step>`
```

and this is ts file

```
`ngOnInit(): void {
this.signupEmail = this.route.snapshot.queryParams.email;
this.restaurantId = +this.route.snapshot.params.id;

this.getHotelsNearby();
this.getRestaurantData();
// this.onConfirmModal();

this.ContactFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
  email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
  name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
  agreement: [false, Validators.requiredTrue]
});


this.PasswordFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
  password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]],
  repeatPW: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]]
}, {
  validator: ConfirmPasswordValidator("password", "repeatPW")
});
```

}`

[this is the red border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzFvz.png)

Comment: Can you upload the code and the image of the input border?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, it will help u to ask question in better way

Comment: iirc an input always instantly evaluates to invalid. In your validation, try adding `ngIf="PasswordFormGroup.dirty` (or `ngIf="PasswordFormGroup.touched"` if you want to show it the error immediately upon clicking the input